# How to update session array via ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, session

> I'm passing user input, which is just quantity and product code in
>   this case to the php script to store into session array via ajax. I
>   expect, each time user clicks submit and the ajax call is made, the
>   quantity and product code will be added into session array. But now
>   what happen is, each time it updates existing data in the session. So
>   only one pair of data exist.

This is my ajax script:

```
<script>
      <!--display form submission result-->
      var param;
      var param2;
      var i;
      function sendToCart(param, param2){
    $("document").ready(function(){
          $("#popup-order").submit(function(){            
            var data = {
              "action": "test"
            };
            data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "addToCart.php?id="+param, //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
              data: data,
              success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
              }
            });
            return false;
          });
        });

      }
    </script>
```

my PHP sendToCart.php

```
   <?php
    session_start();

    $return = $_POST;  
    $return['json']= json_encode($return); 
    $data = json_decode($return['json'], true);

     $_SESSION['cart']=array();
    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], array("quantity"=>$data['qty'],"id"=>$data['id']));
    echo json_encode($cart);
      ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the session variable every time an ajax call is made ...

```
$_SESSION['cart']=array();
```

You need to read the existing session data and add to that data.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code -

```
  if(!is_array($_SESSION['cart']))
    {
      $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    }

    else{
    array_push($_SESSION['cart'],"your desired data");
    }
```